# How can I share a HDD over the internet?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, network-shares, nas

What I want is, to share an external HDD (Let us say drive F:) on the internet so that anyone can access it. The people with access should be able to read/write from/to the HDD directly.

I know this is possible and easy to set up in a local network but I could not find a simple way to do it for someone outside the local network.

Also, I am looking for a simple solution. I am not a big fan of setting up VPNs, or configuring a NAS unless the process is extremely simple both for me and for the person I am sharing it with.

I also used Resilio Sync but that clones all the files and that does not serve my purpose.

Comment: Some routers come with a USB port and allow you to connect a USB hard drive. The router may also support sharing any attached storage devices over the Internet.

Comment: You could also set up an FTP server. Or use cloud storage.

Comment: @DavidPostill My router does not have a USB drive. Also, I do not want to use cloud storage. I wanted a direct link. Also, will an FTP server be accessible to someone outside my personal network?

Comment: FTP server, yes. You might have to setup port forwarding in the router.

Comment: "I wanted a direct link" That's just not possible.

Comment: @DavidPostill How can I configure an FTP server in the simplest way?

Comment: Asking that is off-topic. Do some research and come back when you have  specific questions after you have tried it yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a network drive available over the internet?](https://superuser.com/questions/311658/make-a-network-drive-available-over-the-internet)

Comment: You can use FileZilla or IIS for this tasks and apply anonymous authentication.

Comment: @WasifHasan I did think of FileZilla, but would that let the client edit the files normally? Also, is there any similar app that would let us work in the Windows Explorer? That would be very convenient.

Comment: @harrymc I had already looked into the question but the answer did not really help me. It was quite a complicated method and I just wanted a simple app. I find it a little strange that no such app exists, even if it is a paid app. There are some for enterprise users, but not for basic users like me.

Comment: For a simple app, just use TeamViewer or similar.